# Approval Button bypasses a registered workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, approval-process

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I have a published site.
I, also, attached the built-in publishing approval workflow on the Page library.

However approve/reject button bypasses this workflow:

[image: 102283-03.png]
[image: 102190-04.png]

How to overcome this disadvantage? it seems that approval WF requires to enable content approval.

Comment: I think that the only way of bypassing this, is by creating custom fields and a custom workflow where content will show only if approved.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce the issue in my SharePoint.

As a workaround, click the page, select Approve/Reject under Publish tab, then workflow task form will pop up normally.